# Updating the downloadable products link (and file), when it is changed in admin panel, in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, downloadable

I am not really sure if this is a bug in Magento or I am missing something. Every time I change the file (Add a new file) to a downloadable product in the Admin end, the file does not update for the customers who already bought it and have it in their download list.

I found [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468869/how-to-update-new-downloadable-product-attachment-for-placed-orders-in-magento) for Magento 1.7, I tried it in Magento 2.2 but it did not work. Is there an alternative for Magento 2 as well that anybody is aware of?

Please let me know if there is an obvious way of fixing this and I am missing it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$select = getDb()->select()
    ->from(getTable('downloadable_link'), array('link_id', 'link_file', 'product_id'));

if (($links = getDb()->fetchAll($select)) !== false) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $linkId = $link['link_id'];
        $productId = $link['product_id'];
        $file = $link['link_file'];

        $select = getDb()->select()
            ->from(getTable('downloadable_link_title'), 'title')
            ->where('link_id=?', $linkId)
            ->limit(1);

        $title = getDb()->fetchOne($select);

        echo sprintf("Updating %s to %s<br />", $file, $title);

        $cond = getDb()->quoteInto('product_id=?', $productId);

        getDb()->update(getTable('downloadable_link_purchased_item'), array('link_id' => $linkId, 'link_title' => $title, 'link_file' => $file), $cond);
    }
}

function getDb()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    return $connection = $resource->getConnection();;
}

function getTable($table)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    return $tableName = $resource->getTableName($table);
}
```

Try this. It should work.